# ThreeJS - JSONLoader "Cannot read property 'uniforms' of undefined

Tags: json, 3d, three.js, blender

I'm trying export an object with a texture from Blender. The exported JSON looks like so:

```
 {

    "metadata" :
    {
        "formatVersion" : 3.1,
        "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.66 Exporter",
        "vertices"      : 8,
        "faces"         : 6,
        "normals"       : 8,
        "colors"        : 0,
        "uvs"           : [],
        "materials"     : 1,
        "morphTargets"  : 0,
        "bones"         : 0
    },

    "scale" : 1.000000,

    "materials" : [ {
        "DbgColor" : 15658734,
        "DbgIndex" : 0,
        "DbgName" : "Material",
        "blending" : "NormalBlending",
        "colorAmbient" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
        "colorDiffuse" : [0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865, 0.6400000190734865],
        "colorSpecular" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        "depthTest" : true,
        "depthWrite" : true,
        "mapDiffuse" : "unicorn.jpg",
        "mapDiffuseWrap" : ["repeat", "repeat"],
        "shading" : "Lambert",
        "specularCoef" : 50,
        "transparency" : 1.0,
        "transparent" : false,
        "vertexColors" : false
    }],

    "vertices" : [1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-0.999999,-1,-1,1,1,-0.999999,0.999999,1,1,-1,1,0.999999,-1,1,-1],

    "morphTargets" : [],

    "normals" : [0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349],

    "colors" : [],

    "uvs" : [],

    "faces" : [35,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,35,4,7,6,5,0,4,5,6,7,35,0,4,5,1,0,0,4,7,1,35,1,5,6,2,0,1,7,6,2,35,2,6,7,3,0,2,6,5,3,35,4,0,3,7,0,4,0,3,5],

    "bones" : [],

    "skinIndices" : [],

    "skinWeights" : [],

    "animation" : {}


}
```

My Json loader:

```
 var object;
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();          

loader.load( "models/texturecube.js", function(geometry, materials) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
    object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials); // throws

    object.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    scene.add(object)

});
```

The loader throws "Cannot read property 'uniforms' of undefined" exception. I see that others have to modify the exported JSON to get it to work correctly. Does anyone have an idea what the 'uniforms' property is used for? Should I have this defined in my JSON?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `material` variable is not being used. Do this:

```
object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
```

Also, your geometry will need UVs if you want to be able to apply the texture.

---

EDIT: There is a new pattern. If you have an array of materials, you can now pass the materials array directly into the `Mesh` constructor like so:

```
object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
```

three.js r.87

Comment: Well spotted, I completely missed that.

Comment: Doh.. :) Nice catch indeed. That takes care of the exception. Still no object. Odd that the export did not include them (UVs). I will try exporting again. Perhaps there is a setting I missed.

Comment: I have uv selected for export but the array is still empty in the resulting JSON. Perhaps this is the issue

Comment: If you have more problems, please make a new post -- preferably one that will be helpful to others.

Comment: @WestLangley Sure thing. Ill let you know when I get stuck on something that is more productive for you.

Comment: Being new to Blender I'm assuming I have not mapped my texture correctly. I will research in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing a single material to your object in the line:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials[0]);
```

Instead you need to pass the full array of materials like this:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
```

Essentially what is causing the error is that when your model tries to access any material other than the first it is throwing an `undefined` error because the material does not exist as you haven't passed it to the object constructor.

Comment: Not specifying a specific material still results in the same exception